# Reformat text data convert from integer to time and concatenate with date using sed awk split

Tags: python, linux, awk, sed, apache-spark-sql

I have input data file like this:  (with column names not part of the data file. `Date,Desc,Timestamp1, Timestamp2`) ---

```
2016-01-01, AAA, 330, 1430
2016-01-02, ABA, 130, 930
```

I need to output is as (with column names not part of the data file. Date,Desc,Timestamp1, Timestamp2) ---

```
2016-01-01, AAA, 2016-01-01 03:30, 2016-01-01 14:30
2016-01-02, ABA, 2016-01-02 01:30, 2016-01-02 09:30
```

Please help.
Thank you

Comment: SO is not a coding service. Please include your code and explain why you are not happy with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to contributors.

```
awk '
 BEGIN{FS=","; OFS=", "}
{
  split($2,d,"-"); 
  t0 = mktime(d[1]" "d[2]" "d[3]" "int($5 / 100)" "$5 % 100" 0"); 
  $5 = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", t0); 
  $6 = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", t0 + 3600 * int($6 / 100) + 60 * ($6 % 100))
} 1' afile.txt
```